# Replace a specific format of href with Tampermonkey

Tags: javascript, html, scripting, href

The case is I want to replace in a specific page all links with different client IDs, example:

```
<a href="/clients/725144/detail">Details</a>
```

To this:

```
<a href="/clients/725144/status">Details</a>
```

I have tried many examples but no luck for now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this:

```js
a.setAttribute('href', href.replace(/^(\/clients\/\d+)\/detail$/, '$1/status'))
```

You could even mark linked you updated:

```js
a.dataset.hrefAltered = true
```

```js
const replaceLinks = (pattern, replacement, marker = 'hrefAltered') =>
  document.querySelectorAll('a').forEach(a => {
    const href = a.getAttribute('href');
    if (!a.dataset[marker] && href.match(pattern)) {
      a.setAttribute('href', href.replace(pattern, replacement));
      a.dataset[marker] = true;
      console.log(`UPDATE: href=${a.getAttribute('href')}`);
    }
  });

replaceLinks(/^(\/clients\/\d+)\/detail$/, '$1/status');
```

```html
<a href="/clients/1/detail">Details</a>
<a href="/clients/12/detail">Details</a>
<a href="/clients/123/detail">Details</a>
<a href="/clients/1234/detail">Details</a>
<a href="/clients/12345/detail">Details</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way.

```js
var base = "/clients/725144/detail"

var newBase = ""

if (base.includes("detail")) {
newBase = base.replace("detail", "status");
}

console.log(newBase);
```